# Excel Formula Not showing @

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 2 Excel workbook. One of it I can use @when I click on the column header while the another cannot.

Thus the formula will give error when without the @column name.

Formula without @
[image]

Formula with @
[image]

Sorry, I am unable to make the picture show in this post as it only allow a hyperlink.

Anyone know how to enable the @column name function in formula?

Comment: Make your data a table and you can use table references

Comment: You can see the difference also within the ribbon: the second table has an additional tab "Table Design"

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd screenshot has a tab "Table Design" on the right whereas the 1st screenshot doesn't have that (only filter is applied). As the comments mentioned, remove the filter and convert to a Table (Ctrl + T).
It is also worth mentioning that you can select any range to convert to a table whereas applying a filter may not work if you have empty cells in your data.